# WooCommerce programmatically added fee don't persists

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I am adding a custom fee to the cart by hooking into the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` action like so:

```
    if (isset($_GET['discount'])) {



        add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_loyalty_discounts');
    }

    function add_loyalty_discounts(WC_Cart $cart)
    {
        $total = 0;

        global $woocommerce;

        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $item) {

            $total += $item['data']->regular_price;

            $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['discount_amount'] = $_GET['discount'];
        }

        if ($total < $_GET['discount']) {
            wc_add_notice('You must spend more than €' . $_GET['discount'] . ' to use your loyalty discount.', 'error');
        } else {

            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

            $loyalty_points = empty(get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'loyalty_points', true)) ? 0 : get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'loyalty_points', true);

            $loyalty_points  = 100;

            if ($loyalty_points < $_GET['discount']) {
                wc_add_notice('You do not have enough loyalty points to apply this discount.', 'error');
            } else {

                $cart->add_fee('Loyalty Discount',   -intval($_GET['discount']), true);
            }
        }
    }
```

The fee appears on the cart page but not persist onto the checkout and order pages.

I've tried using `$cart->set_session()` but this had no effect.

Update: I have created a fresh WP site with a blank theme (blankslate), and only the latest version of WooCommerce installed and I still get the error.

Comment: As this seems a bug related to something else, first make a database backup… Enable WP debug (as explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61754061/3730754)), browse your site with the fee enabled and then check in the debug.log file. Then try to switch to Storefront theme (to see if that is not related to your theme). If it's not the case try to disable all plugins except wooCommerce and check. If the problem is gone, a plugin is making trouble: enable back the plugins one by one and check each time if the fee works…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks, I have scanned all the plugins and the theme for functions which could effect the cart and have not found anything.  I will make a copy of the site and try disabling everything.

Comment: OK, I have created a fresh theme, disabled all the plugins except the latest version of WooCommerce, and it is still not persisting.

Comment: So something is wrong in that fresh theme. Try to upload Storefront theme, and enable it. Add your code in the functions.php file… It should work.

Comment: It's  a blank theme, there is nothing in it apart from my code. I will try store front now.

Comment: Ah I've got it, I take it `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` runs on the checkout page as well as the cart page, I am only adding the fee on the cart page.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Does that sound right to you?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that the added fee would not persist and need to be readded.

Comment: Maybe I should suggest it to Automattic.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec well no, it wasn't a problem with the theme, it was a miss understanding of how the `WC_Cart` persists fee data.

Comment: I've added a feature request on the WooCommerce github repo.

Comment: The problem comes from the usage of `$_GET['discount']`. I have updated my code, with your newly added code… please have a look to it and try.

Comment: Another quick question:  Do you know why `cart->get_total` returns an different amount to the sum of the individual cart item prices?

Comment: You can't use it in that hook, as you will get an infinite loop or a wrong amount, because the fee is added to that total. Always use a subtotal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** *(based on your newly added code)*

You can't use `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` in `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook, as those variables will be lost. Instead, you should store your $_GET['discount'] in a WC_Session variable.

Now, your code is outdated, there are some mistakes and missing things.

Try the following revisited code instead:

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'save_discount_in_session');
function save_discount_in_session() {
    if ( isset($_GET['discount']) ) {
        WC()->session->set('loyalty_discount', floatval($_GET['discount']));
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_loyalty_discounts');
function add_loyalty_discounts($cart){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $discount = (float) WC()->session->get('loyalty_discount');
    $subtotal = (float) WC()->cart->subtotal;

    if ( $discount > 0 ) {
        if ( $subtotal >= $discount ) {
            $loyalty_points = (int) get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'loyalty_points', true);
    
            if ( $loyalty_points >= $discount ) {
                $cart->add_fee( __('Loyalty Discount'), -$discount );
            } else {
                wc_clear_notices();
                wc_add_notice( __('You do not have enough loyalty points to apply this discount.'), 'error');
            }
        } else {
            wc_clear_notices();
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You must spend more than %s to use your loyalty discount.'), wc_price($discount) ), 'error');
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

---

To apply the fee only in checkout page, you will use:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_loyalty_discounts');
function add_loyalty_discounts($cart) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( is_cart() )
        return;
        
    $cart->add_fee('Loyalty Discount', -100);
}
```

Related:

- [Quantity discount of one free product in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76986989/quantity-discount-of-one-free-product-in-woocommerce/76987112#76987112)
- [WooCommerce Buyback custom Plugin: How to update user Wallet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76960577/woocommerce-buyback-custom-plugin-how-to-update-user-wallet/76967048#76967048)
- [Apply a discount for a specific user role in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889136/apply-a-discount-for-a-specific-user-role-in-woocommerce/54890439#54890439)

Comment: That doesn't look right to me, why is it returning if it's not admin and not doing ajax?  I am testing it using an admin account and it is not running in an ajax call.

Comment: On all that kind of hooks that can be triggered by Ajax, we use that to prevent an error on the backend... See [all that threads using this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees), most of them include that. Also I know what I am talking about As I have nearly 200 answers using that hook.

Comment: Sorry, I am sure your right, your answers have helped me many times.  I just didn't understand why it was returning if an admin user was logged in as I do want the function to execute if I am an admin user.

Comment: Anyway, do you have any idea why I am get an empty array on the checkout page even after updating the `add_fee` function with the `true`.

Comment: The [conditional function `is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) target the backend, not the "administrator" users. Now in `add_fee()` method the 3rd argument that you have set to `true` is related to taxes (taxable). I can't guess by magic about that issue you are facing, sorry. You may have to enable WP_DEBUG temporarily, as explained [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61754061/3730754), to see if there is not something else making trouble.

Comment: I see, my mistake, I really should know that as I've just used `current_user_can('manage_options')` to check if it is an admin user.  You live and you learn.

Comment: Thanks for the update Loic, that is a neat solution to the problem.  But I really do think that WooCommerce should persist the fees.  Will your code update the Order total or do I need to apply the discount on Order creation?

Comment: And thanks for filling in the missing elements and updating the code.  It really is appreciated.

Comment: My thinking is that once the fee has been set it should persist to the other cart stages.  I understand that the $_GET variable is not permanent, but if the cart fee persisted in the cart meta data (rather than having to readd the fee at each stage) then there would be no need to store the $_GET variable in the session.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot make sense of this statement : `but if you add before an if statement that don't persist, the fee doesn't persist either`,  surely once the fee is set it should persist.  On the cart I am setting a fee in the cart page which is set with the `$_GET` ,that fee does not exist in the checkout page and needs to be readded, I don't think that it should need to be added again.

Answer (score 0):

I tested and it works fine with me on both cart and checkout page

```
function add_loyalty_discounts(WC_Cart $cart) {
        $cart->add_fee('Loyalty Discount', -intval(100), true);
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_loyalty_discounts');
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is odd, when I try `$cart->get_fees()` on the checkout page is returns an empty array;

Comment: @franka some plugins overrides your fees?? did you try to disable everything?

Comment: Yes because the fee is setup only on the cart page, so you would need to setup session flag by adding true to the add_fee function

Comment: Adding true to the `add_fee` function results in the fee amount as 0.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: Then the get variable is not setup properly try to put static value and test the script

Comment: Sorry I added the true in the `intval` function that's why it resulted in 0.  But adding true to the `add_fee` function has not solved my issue.  I can fins anything overriding the fee's.

Comment: The fee appears when I do `$cart->get_fees()` on the cart page but on the checkout page it returns an empty array.

Comment: I've added the full function.

Comment: Can you add the full function and test again @fr

Comment: I've added the full function and have tested it still does not persist.  There's no other plugins which effect the cart.  I am baffled.

Comment: Is your website live? to test and check?

Comment: Your code does not set a session, it effects the tax.

Comment: I don't know why it is not working with you, I tested on live enviroment and it works

Answer (score 0):

The reason is was not adding the fee is because I only added the fee on the cart page. The `WC_Cart` class does not persist fee's.